# How did the Pakleds get Romulan shields?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I understand how the Pakleds nearly obtained photon torpedo capabilities from the U.S.S. Enterprise, but that kind of ruse wouldn't work on the Romulans. Romulans are much less kind than the Enterprise crew, and if the Pakleds had asked for help with their guidance system, at best the Romulan vessel would have sent instructions and left.

Yet the Mondor that the Enterprise ran into in 'The Samaritan Snare' seemed to have multiple Romulan systems. I looked it up, but can't find any reference to a Pakled encounter with Romulans at all.

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect the Pakleds had numerous ploys in their bag of tricks to gather tech. They surely were more clever than they were technologically advanced. Lulling your opponent into underestimating you is a very old tactic. "We look for things, things we need. Things to make us go."

Comment: True, but it seems like the Romulans would sooner open fire than let the Pakleds escape with their tech. The Mondor didn't have warp capabilities, and with Romulan ships specifically designed to blow things up on their tail they would be destroyed even with shields.

Comment: Yep, the Romulans would have probably ignored them after the first 2 minutes of conversation or just as casually boarded them, slapped them around, or just blew them up out of disgust. Most likely they came by the tech through some 3rd party 'acquisition'.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing in canon that would provide a definite answer to this particular question.

- It could be that they scavenged the technology from a wreck and then had help making it work.
- They might have acquired it through an intermediate - the Ferengi, for example.

Comment: Good point about an intermediary. The Pakleds could have obtained things or technology of value from another species and traded them away to the Ferengi in exchange for shields. The Ferengi will sell to anyone if the price is right.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Pakleds have a pretty good understanding of what alien races are dangerous or not. They must if they're still alive as a species. They probably know they're more likely to fleece a Federation ship than Romulan or Klingon.

Most likely it was a Romulan ship that crash-landed in their system. Probably could've been something like that that caused them to get into space prematurely.

Picture an alien ship crashing on Earth while it was still populated by homo erectus.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFFSE!  Unfortunately this answer contains primarily speculation rather than canon-based answers, which is what we strive for here.  If you could add some sources to back you up, that would be great!